# How to get a property value from a MemberExpression

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to get the property value via a MemberExpression.

For example, given the following object, I want to get the Guid value in the "Id" property.

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id {get; set}
}
```

I have an event being called which has a MemberExpression passed to that event.  The MemberExpression parameter represents the Employee.Id property.  How can I get the **VALUE** of "Id" from the MemberExpression?  The code I'm trying to use is as follows:

```
(MemberExpression employeeIdMember is parameter to the event)
if ((employeeIdMember.Member as PropertyInfo) != null)
{
    PropertyInfo employeeIdProperty = employeeIdMember.Member as PropertyInfo;
    // at this point employeeIdProperty represents {System.Guid Id}

    PropertyInfo parentObject = (MemberExpression)employeeIdMember.Expression).Member as PropertyInfo;
    // at this point, parentObject represents {BusinessObjects.Employee Employee}

    // HOW to call employeeIdProperty.GetValue(parentObject) to get the Id Property Value?? I've tried this call here, but it does not work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at this point you have 2 properties to make you double indirection.

it miss a entry point : a reference to "BusinessObjects"

then call

```
var businessObjects = ???
var id = employeeIdProperty.GetValue(parentObject.GetValue(businessObjects));
```